# Rerender not working after first time

Tags: class, visualforce

I need to refresh a separate pageblock by keeping another pageblock as it is. I am having a picklist in a pageblock and it contains 1 to 10. If I select first time that pageblock only gets refreshed but if I change any picklist value its not working. please provide me a solution

VF code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="RForce_ES_Web2Case_Extn" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" id="pge">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/css/validationEngine.jquery.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<!---MaskPlugin---->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion1}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion}"/>
<!---ValidationPlugin---->
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery_min.js')}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>



<style>
form{
   width:540px;
   background-color:#EDEDED;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
div #button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
input.text {
    border: 1px solid #DADCDE;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
p{
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: #A2A5A4; 
    font-size: o.70em; 
}
h2{
    line-height: 1.5px;
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#CPF_Web__c,#email,#Phone,#Fname1,#Lname1,#description,#VIN_Web__c,#License_Number_Web__c,#Address,#CEP,#Complemento,#Cidade,#Estado,#ContactMobile{
    width: 410px;
}
#Numero{
    width: 150px;
}
#Endereço{
    width: 410px;
}
#left {
   float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
div #backbutton{
    float: right;
}
</style>

<Script>
function validate(data,name)
{
    var labelName = name;
    var inputValue = data.value;
    if(name=='Fname')
    {
        callFirstName(inputValue);
     }

    if(name=='Lname')
    {

        callLastName(inputValue);    
        }

    if(name=='Surname')
    {

        callSecondSurName(inputValue);    
        }  

    if(name=='email')
    {

        callEmail(inputValue);    
        }   

    if(name=='phone')
    {

        callPhone(inputValue);    
        }    

    if(name=='ContactMobile')
    {

        callContactMobile(inputValue);    
    }  

    if(name=='number')
    {

        callNumber(inputValue);    
    }   

    if(name=='Street')
    {

        callStreet(inputValue);    
    }  

    if(name=='flat')
    {

        callFlat(inputValue);    
    }   

    if(name=='door')
    {

        callDoor(inputValue);    
    } 

    if(name=='city')
    {

        callCity(inputValue);    
    }   

    if(name=='state')
    {

        callState(inputValue);    
    }   

    if(name=='vinno')
    {

        callVINNo(inputValue);    
    }     


    if(name=='RegNo')
    {

        callRegNo(inputValue);    
    }     

    if(name=='km')
    {

        callKM(inputValue);    
    }   

    if(name=='casetype' )
    {
        callCaseType(inputValue);    
    }

    if(name=='descriptionvalid')
    {
    callDesc(inputValue);

    }

}

function picklistvalidate()
{
var titleId = document.getElementById("casetype");
var titleValue= titleId.options[titleId .selectedIndex].value;
alert('title value 2 is ' + titleValue);
callCaseType(titleValue); 
}

</Script>


<!--<script>

function desc(data)
{
var inputValue = data.value;
alert('Desc value called'+   inputValue);
callDesc(inputValue);

}
</script>-->

</head>  

<form id="formID" >  
    <Label >Si quiere realizar una consulta, una reclamación o hacer una sugerencia, cumplimente por favor el formulario a continuación.Para poder gestionar su petición, necesitamos por favor algunos datos personales.
    </Label>
<br></br><hr color = "white"></hr>        
        <br></br>

     <label for="Title_Web__c"> Tratamiento*</label><br/>
        <select  id="Title_Web__c" class="validate[required]" name="Title_Web__c" onchange = "picklistvalidate();">
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="Sr.">Sr.</option>
            <option value="Sra.">Sra.</option>
            <option value="Sta">Sta.</option>
        </select><br/>
        <hr color="white"></hr>


<Label for="Lname" >APELLIDO 1*</Label>      
 <br></br> 
<input id="Lname" value="{!sLastname}" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input " maxlength="20" name="FirstName_Web__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:500px" oninput="validate(this,'Lname');"/>
<br></br>

<span>       
<Label for="Fname" >NOMBRE*</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<Label for="Surname" >APELLIDO 2*</Label>
<br></br>

<input id="Fname" value="{!sFirstname}" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="30" name="FirstName_Web__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" oninput="validate(this,'Fname');"/> 
&nbsp;
<input id="Surname" value="{!sSecondSurname}" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="20" name="Surname__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:235px" oninput="validate(this,'Surname');"/>
</span>

  <hr color="white"></hr>

  <Label for="email" >E-mail*</Label><br></br>
   <input id="email" value="{!sEmail}" maxlength="80" size="48" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" style="width:500px" oninput="validate(this,'email');"/>

    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="phone" >Teléfono fijo</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="phone" value="{!sTelephone}" class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]]" maxlength="9" name="phone" size="48" style="width:500px" oninput="validate(this,'phone');"/>
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="Mobile">Teléfono móvil*</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="ContactMobile" value="{!sMobilePhone}" class="validate[optional,custom[telephone]]" maxlength="9" size="48"  name="Cell_Phone_Web__c"  style="width:500px" oninput="validate(this,'ContactMobile');"/>
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>
<span>    
  <hr color="white"></hr>    
<Label for="Dnumber" >Nº</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
<Label for="Street" >Calle</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="number" value="{!sNo}" class="validate[optional ,custom[noSpecialCaracters]]"  maxlength="20" name="Dnumber__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" oninput="validate(this,'number');"/>
&nbsp;
<input id="Street" value="{!sStreet}" class="validate[optional ,custom[noSpecialCaracters]]" maxlength="20" name="Street__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" oninput="validate(this,'Street');"/>
</span>  

<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="flat" >Piso</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="door" >Puerta</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="flat" value="{!sFlat}" class="validate[optional ,custom[noSpecialCaracters]]"  maxlength="20" name="Flat__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" oninput="validate(this,'flat');"/>
&nbsp;
<input id="door" value="{!sDoor}" class="validate[optional ,custom[noSpecialCaracters]]" maxlength="20" name="Door__c" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" oninput="validate(this,'door');"/>
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="city" >Ciudad</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="state" >Provincia</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="city" value="{!sCity }" class="validate[length[2,20]]"  maxlength="20" name="City__c" size="20" type="text" oninput="validate(this,'city');"/>
&nbsp;
<input id="state" value="{!sState }" class="validate[length[2,20]]"  maxlength="20" name="State__c" size="20" type="text" oninput="validate(this,'state');"/>
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="vin" >Chasis</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<Label for="regno" >Matricula</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="vinno" value="{!sVIN}"  class="validate[clength]"  maxlength="17" name="Vin__c" size="20" type="text" oninput="validate(this,'vinno');"/>
&nbsp;
<input id="RegNo" value="{!sRegNo}"  maxlength="20" name="Regnio__c" size="20" type="text" oninput="validate(this,'RegNo');"/>
</span>  

<br></br> 
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<Label for="km">Kilómetros</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="km" value="{!sKilometer}" type="number" oninput="validate(this,'km');"/> 
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
               <Label for="casetype">Tipo*</Label><br></br> 
               <select  id="casetype" class="validate[required]" name="casetype" onchange = "picklistvalidate();">
               <option value="None">None</option>
               <option value="Solicitud de información">Solicitud de información</option>
               <option value="Reclamación">Reclamación</option>
               <option value="Sugerencia">Sugerencia</option>
               <option value="Other">Other</option>
               </select><br/>
               <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>

<!--<Label for="description">Descripción*</Label><br></br>
<Textarea  id="descriptionvalid" value="{!sDescription}" name="Description" class="validate[required]"  maxlength = "800" rows="8" cols="57" onblur= "validate(this,'descriptionvalid');"/>    
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>-->
  </form>


  <apex:form id="page">

<apex:actionFunction name="callFirstName" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sFirstname" value="Fname" assignTo="{!sFirstname}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callLastName" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sLastname" value="" assignTo="{!sLastname}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callSecondSurName" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sSecondSurname" value="" assignTo="{!sSecondSurname}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callEmail" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sEmail" value="email" assignTo="{!sEmail}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callPhone" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sTelephone" value="phone" assignTo="{!sTelephone}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callContactMobile" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sMobilePhone" value="ContactMobile" assignTo="{!sMobilePhone}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callNumber" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sNo" value="number" assignTo="{!sNo}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callStreet" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sStreet" value="Street" assignTo="{!sStreet}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callFlat" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sFlat" value="flat" assignTo="{!sFlat}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callDoor" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sDoor" value="door" assignTo="{!sDoor}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callCity" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sCity" value="city" assignTo="{!sCity}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callState" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sState" value="state" assignTo="{!sState}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callVINNo" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sVIN" value="vinno" assignTo="{!sVIN}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callRegNo" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sRegNo" value="RegNo" assignTo="{!sRegNo}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callKM" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sKilometer" value="km" assignTo="{!sKilometer}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callCaseType" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sCasetype" value="casetype" assignTo="{!sCasetype}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="callDesc" action="{!createcase}" rerender="">
<apex:param name="sDescription" value="descriptionvalid" assignTo="{!sDescription}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<input type="hidden" name="CaseBrand__C" value="Dacia" />

        <input type="hidden" name="priority" value="Normal"/>                              
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="New"/>  
        <input type="hidden" name="origin" value="DACIA SITE"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="Language_Web__c" name="Language_Web__c" value="Spanish"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="CaseSubSource__c" value="Webform"/>     
        <input type="hidden" id="From" name="From__c" value="Customer"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="recordType" name="recordType" value="{!$Label.RForce_ESCaseRecordType}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="CountryCase" name="CountryCase__c" title="Country Case" value="Spain"/>

   <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageblocksection >
<form>
<span class="validate[required]">
   <apex:outputLabel for="description">Descripción*</apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                   <apex:inputTextarea id="description" value="{!sDescription }" onblur="validate(this,'descriptionvalid')" onfocus="validate[required]" rows="8" cols="57" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>
                    </span>
                    </form>
   </apex:pageblocksection>
   </apex:pageblock>
   <apex:pageBlock id="blockid">
<apex:pageblocksection > 
              <apex:actionFunction name="ChangeCount" action="{!ChangeCount}" rerender="blockid" />    
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >   
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Número de datos adjuntos?"/>   
                    <apex:selectList onchange="ChangeCount() ;" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!sFileCount}">   
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemValue=""/>   
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!filesCountList}"/>   
                    </apex:selectList>   
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   
            </apex:pageblocksection>                 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Seleccionar archivos" rendered="{!IF(sFileCount != null && sFileCount != '', true , false)}">   
                <apex:repeat value="{!allFileList}" var="AFL">   
                    <apex:inputfile value="{!AFL.body}" filename="{!AFL.Name}" />   
                    <br></br>
                </apex:repeat>   
            </apex:pageBlockSection>              
              <apex:commandButton value="Enviar"  action="{!createCase11}" />           
         </apex:pageBlock>  

  </apex:form> 


</apex:page>
```

Controller code :

```
public with sharing class RForce_ES_Web2Case_Extn {
    public String sDescription {get;set;}
    public String sFilename{get; set;}
    public String sFirstname{get;set;}
    public String sLastname{get;set;}
    public String sSecondSurname{get;set;}
    public String sEmail{get;set;}
    public String sTelephone{get;set;}
    public String sMobilePhone{get;set;}
    public String sCity {get;set;}
    public String sState {get;set;}
    public String sVIN {get;set;}
    public String sRegNo {get;set;}
    public String sKilometer {get;set;}
    public String sNo {get;set;}
    public String sFlat {get;set;}
    public String sStreet {get;set;}
    public String sDoor {get;set;}
    public String sCaseType{get;set;}
    public String Namefirst{get;set;}

    public Boolean bCaseStatus = false;
    public List<SelectOption> filesCountList {get; set;}   
    //Selected count   
    public String sFileCount {get; set;}  
    public List<Attachment> allFileList {get; set;}   


    public Blob blobFilebody {get; set;}
    public selectoption[] optSalutation{set;get;}
    public selectoption[] optCaseType{set;get;}
    public void myApexMethod(){
        system.debug('sEmail--->'+sEmail);
    }
    public Rforce_ES_Web2Case_Extn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {



         //Initialize     
         filesCountList = new List<SelectOption>() ;   
        sFileCount = '' ;   
        allFileList = new List<Attachment>() ;   

        //Adding values count list - you can change this according to your need   
        for(Integer i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++)   
            filesCountList.add(new SelectOption(''+i , ''+i)) ;

    }   

     // }    
    public static boolean addAttachment(Case cas, List<Attachment> allFileList, String sFileCount  )   
    {   
        if(sFileCount == null || sFileCount == '')   
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select how many files you want to upload.'));   

        List<Attachment> listToInsert = new List<Attachment>() ;   

        for(Attachment a: allFileList)   
        {   
            if(a.name != '' && a.name != '' && a.body != null)   
                listToInsert.add(new Attachment(parentId = cas.Id, name = a.name, body = a.body)) ;   
        }   


        try{
            if(listToInsert.size()>0){
                insert listToInsert;
                sFileCount = '' ; 
            }                      
        }catch(DmlException e) {
         System.debug('An exception occurred:' + e.getMessage());
         }catch(Exception e) {
         System.debug('An Generic exception occurred:' + e.getMessage());
         } finally {
         }
         return true; 
    }   

    public void  ChangeCount()   
    {    
            allFileList.clear() ;  


        //Adding multiple attachments instance   
        for(Integer i = 1 ; i <= Integer.valueOf(sFileCount) ; i++)   
            allFileList.add(new Attachment()) ;


         // System.debug('Test Fname===>'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Fname'));

    }

    public static boolean insertCase(Case c)
    {
        try{
        //Perform some database operations that  might cause an exception.
        insert c;                       
        }catch(DmlException e) {
        // DmlException handling code here.
        System.debug('An exception occurred:' + e.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e) {
        // Generic exception handling code here.
        System.debug('An Generic exception occurred:' + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
        // Perform some clean up.                    
        }                                                                       
        if(c.id != null){
        return true;          
        }          
        else{
        return false;
        }                   
    }       

public void createCase() { 

      /* System.debug('Test Fname===>'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Fname')); not working
       String Namefirst = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sFirstname');
       System.debug('Test sFirstname===>'+Namefirst );
          System.Debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> ');

      sFirstname = Namefirst;

         */
      }

public PageReference doSubmit(){

System.Debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> inside dosubmit  --> ');


        String sCaseStatus = 'New';
        String sCaseBrand = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseBrand__C');
        system.debug('Inside Dosubmit' + sCaseBrand  );
        String sLanguage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Language_Web__c');
        String sSubject = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('subject');
        String sPriority = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('priority');
        String sStatus = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('status');
        String sOrigin = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('origin');
        String sCaseSubSource = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseSubSource__c');
        String sFrom = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('From__c');
        String sExternal = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('external');
        String sRecordType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordType');
        system.debug('1234'+sRecordType);
        String sCountryCase = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CountryCase__c');

        Case c = new Case ( Subject = sCaseType,CaseBrand__C=sCaseBrand, CaseSubSource__c = sCaseSubSource , Description = sDescription , Cell_Phone_Web__c = sMobilePhone ,  License_Number_Web__c = sRegNo , SuppliedEmail = sEmail ,  FirstName_Web__c = sFirstname, LastName_Web__c = sLastname, City_Web__c =sCity , State_Web__c = sState , SuppliedPhone = sTelephone , Status = sCaseStatus , Origin = sOrigin , VIN_Web__c = sVIN ,  priority = sPriority , Language_Web__c = sLanguage , From__c = sFrom , CountryCase__c = sCountryCase , Address_Web__c = sNo + sStreet + sFlat + sDoor );     
        try {
        system.debug('Inside Try');
            bCaseStatus = insertCase(c);
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Exception while insert' +e.getMessage());
        }     
        finally {
        if(bCaseStatus = true){

        system.debug('allFileList -------->'+allFileList);
         system.debug('sFileCount -------->'+sFileCount );           
        addAttachment(c, allFileList, sFileCount );
        }
        }
                //Attachment att = new Attachment (Name = sFilename, Body = blobFilebody, ParentId = c.Id);
       // insert att;
       if(sCaseBrand == 'Dacia')
       {
        system.debug('9999999>' + sCaseBrand);

        return new PageReference('http://www.dacia.es/');
        }
        else
        {
        system.debug('9999999>');
        return new PageReference('http://www.renault.es/');
        } 
     }     
     public pagereference createCase11() {
     system.debug('<<<<<<<inside createcase'+sFirstname);
     if( sFirstname!=null )
     {
     system.debug('<<<<<<<inside if');
      return doSubmit();
     } 
     else{
      system.debug('<<<<<<<inside else');
       return null;
     }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refine your question to problem area.

There seems to be a controller level error that is occuring. Please add `<apex:pagemessage/>` and `<apex:pagemessages/>` in the rerendered section. It would show the page level(validation) and controller level failures.

Comment: can u please tell where I have to add the <apex:pagemessage> ?

Comment: you could create a new section and add it there for debugging purpose, and rerender it along with other sections....Or, add to which ever section is already getting rerendered...add the attribute 'severity="error"'